# Removing every other element in NumPy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I can't for the life of me figure this out.

I'm trying to remove every other element in the second axis of an array. I did this in MATLAB with `arr(:,:,2:2:end) = [];`, but when I tried to do the same in Python and compare the two outputs, I get a different matrix.

I've tried `arr = np.delete(arr,np.arange(0,arr.shape[2],2),2)` and `arr = arr[:,:,1::2]`, but neither seem to come up with something I get with MATLAB.

---

Example:


MATLAB

```
    disp(['before: ',str(arr[21,32,11])])
    arr(:,:,2:2:end) = [];
    disp(['after: ',str(arr[21,32,11])])
```

output:

```
    before: 99089
    after: 65699
```

Python

```
    print 'before: ' + str(arr[20,31,10])
    arr = arr[:,:,1::2] # same output as np.delete(arr,np.arange(0,arr.shape[2],2),2) 
    print 'after: ' + str(arr[20,31,10])
```

output:

```
    before: 99089
    after: 62360
```

I hope I'm not overlooking something fundamental.

Comment: How about just `arr = arr[:,:,::2]`?

Comment: @Divakar Okay, that actually fixed everything. Do you mind explaining why `::2` works differently than `1::2`?

Comment: Well `[1::2]` starts indexing from `[1]` i.e. `2nd` element onwards, but you want from the `1st` i.e. `[0]` element onwards. So, alternatively, you can do `arr = arr[:,:,0::2]` to mean the same thing and effect.

Comment: @Divakar Actually, I realized I made a typo in my MATLAB example. It should be `arr(:,:,2:2:end) = [];` (I'm not sure how I managed to mess that up). Regardless, your answer seems to fix the problem I had, but shouldn't I be starting from `[1]th` in Python if I want to match MATLAB?

Comment: With `arr[:,:,::2]` we are selecting elements and with `=[];` we are deleting stuffs. So, that sort of *flips* things around.

Comment: @Divakar But in my MATLAB example, I had it start from the second element onward (`2:2:end`) whereas the equivalent in Python seems to be `0::2`. Is this a quirk in my code or does Python behave differently than MATLAB when it comes to selecting elements? Also, you can put your first response in an answer so I can close the question.

Comment: @David - In MATLAB, you are **removing** every even slice, which is the same thing as **selecting** every odd slice.  In `numpy`, Divakar is simply selecting every odd slice whereas in MATLAB, you are removing every even slice.  The two operations are equivalent, but one is selecting out elements while the other is removing.  It's better if you select out the elements rather than deleting them from the array.  The amount of time it takes is also costly for larger sized matrices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to delete every other element starting from the second element onwards in the last axis. In other words, you are trying to keep every other element starting from the first element onwards in that axis.

Thus, working the *other way* around of selecting elements instead of deleting elements, the MATLAB code `arr(:,:,2:2:end) = []` would be equivalent to (neglecting the performance numbers) :

```
arr = arr(:,:,1:2:end)
```

In Python/NumPy, this would be:

```
arr = arr[:,:,0::2]
```

Or simply:

```
arr = arr[:,:,::2]
```

Comment: Ah, now it makes perfect sense! Thank you for taking the time to explain it :)

Comment: @David Awesome, kool!